# Git stopped working after installing both Github osx client and RailsInstaller

Tags: install, macos, git

Perhaps it was due to some conflict but now when typing git I get a blank line, it doesn't say command not found, just goes to the next line

If I press return, it exits, and does nothing

How do I reinstall / remove everything and start from scratch?

I'm a new mac user, so please don't assume I know anything obvious

Comment: @christianmbrodbeck I get `/usr/bin/git` which is the git installed probably by railsinstaller. 
the git version I want (dmg downloaded from git-scm.com) is located at `/usr/local/git/bin`. 

how do I switch the which? :)

Comment: Which version of OS X?

Comment: Latest, Mountain Lion I think, I resolved the issue by the way, I'll post the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to uninstall the git version that railsinstaller (allegedly) installed
(I could have just removed any file that starts with `git` in `/usr/bin` but it doesn't seem right)

What I did was just change the system path, which I thought should be trivial

well, apparently there are quite a *few* [places](https://superuser.com/questions/69130/where-does-path-get-set-in-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard), here are a few from that answer (not in order)

```
/etc/profile
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_login
~/.profile   
~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
/etc/paths
/etc/paths.d/
```

Eventually, what helped was to change `/etc/paths` (had to learn a bit vim to do so)

I moved `/usr/local/git/bin` to be the first entry, above `/usr/bin` and that was about it